# window.close() on a popup back to original tab in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, safari, cross-browser

I have a Twitter authorization flow that works perfectly in most browsers. You click "Add a Twitter Account" which has a `target="_blank"` attribute that sends the user over to Twitter without leaving my site, they authorize, and Twitter sends the user back to a page on my site. That page triggers something with `window.opener` (the parent window) and then closes the window.

The event is properly triggered on the original window, however there is a case when a user has multiple tabs open in Safari (and maybe other browsers), the new window will open in the last tab, and thus when I execute `window.close()`, it takes the user to whatever the last tab is now instead of my site. Is there any way to bring the user back to my site aside from removing `target="_blank"` and going through the flow that way?

Comment: Why are you bothering to open a new window? Just use the twitter OAuth API and the same window. `target="_blank"` has been depreciated for a reason: it's intrusive.

Comment: Hmm. I stand corrected. It was depreciated in XHTML but HTML5 seems to allow it again. Oh well, it's still terrible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's a browser configuration, and allowing a script to access it would be a security flaw

What you can do is to not use window.open, but rather open it in an iframe.

There's a lot of jQuery plugins that do this for you, take a look at [ThickBox's iFrame examples](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#sectione-1)

Comment: Agree 100%. Authorization by opening a new window is stupid and intrusive.

Comment: thanks guys, for whatever reason it skipped my mind to open this page in an iframe. Of course I am using OAuth, ghoppe, but part of that flow is having the user grant you access on their side.